# How to match second group of digit in a alphanumeric string

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to query for both the first and the second group of digits of a string on a MySQL table but after some attempts I only got the first group of digits to match and a copy of it as "the second group".

**The query I used:**

`SELECT DISTINCT rif,REGEXP_SUBSTR(rif,"[0-9]+") AS num1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(rif, "[0-9]+") AS num2 FROM "table" WHERE rif LIKE "%205 QUEEN%"`

**And here is the output it returns:**

| rif | num1 | num2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 205 QUEEN-1012-K | 205 | 205 |
| 205 QUEEN-711-K | 205 | 205 |
| 205 QUEEN-905-K | 205 | 205 |

**Desired output:**

| rif | num1 | num2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 205 QUEEN-1012-K | 205 | 1012 |
| 205 QUEEN-711-K | 205 | 711 |
| 205 QUEEN-905-K | 205 | 905 |

How can I alter the query for it to return the desired output? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function needs additional parameters

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(rif, "[0-9]+",1,2) as num2
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much! Also, do you know what those parameters do or their definition?

Comment: the first one is, at what position of the string to start the search
the second one is which occurrence of the regexp expression to find,
you can read up on it into more detail on the mysql documentation